# Reading random input from file

Tags: c, file, scanf

I have a file and I want to read some random input from file, I don't want to use `getline` or some things like that, the scanning works but it reads some random stuff, like null or different characters. I think the problem could be when i am reading a single character and that might destroy all this.

Here is some code to see what I did:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct queries
{
    char type;
    int node;
    char *addr;
} Queries;

int main()
{
    int i;
    FILE *f;

    f = fopen("queries.in", "r");

    if (!f)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "File queries.in was not opened correctly.\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    int n_queries;

    fscanf(f, "%d\n", &n_queries);

    Queries *q = (Queries*)malloc(n_queries*sizeof(struct queries));

    for (i = 0; i < n_queries; ++i)
    {
        fscanf(f, "%c ", &q[i].type);
        if(q[i].type == 'q')  fscanf(f, "%d %s\n", &q[i].node, q[i].addr);
        else fscanf(f, "%d\n", &q[i].node);
    }

    for (i = 0; i < n_queries; ++i)
    {
        printf("%d %c ", i, q[i].type);
        if(q[i].type == 'q') printf("%d %s\n", q[i].node, q[i].addr);
        else printf("%d\n", q[i].node);
    }

    fclose(f);
}
```

And here is the input:

```
8
q 0 addr2
q 0 addr1
q 0 addr1
q 1 addr4
q 1 addr1
q 1 addr2
f 4
q 1 addr4
```

Well expected output:

```
8
q 0 addr2
q 0 addr1
q 0 addr1
q 1 addr4
q 1 addr1
q 1 addr2
f 4
q 1 addr4
```

Actual output:

```
0 q 0 (null)
1 a 0
2 d 0
3 d 0
4 r 2
5 q 0 (null)
6 a 0
7 d 0
```

I have no idea what's going on

Comment: Rather than the nearly useless `fprintf(stderr, "File queries.in was not opened correctly.\n");` try `perror("queries.in")`  The former gives no hint as to what went wrong.  The latter tells you the reason the file couldn't be opened.

Comment: @WilliamPursell Hello, thank you! What about on memory allocation? Can I use ```perror``` there too?

Comment: `perror` can be used with any function that assigns a value to the global `errno` on error.  `malloc` sets `errno` on error.

Comment: @WilliamPursell How do you use it on ```malloc```?

Comment: Sadly, it's not usually particularly useful with malloc, but you use it as with any other function.  When a function that assigns `errno` on error returns a value to indicate an error, you can call `perror` to print the system error message associated with that value of `errno` to stderr.  Be careful that you don't change `errno` between the failing call and the call to `perror` (eg, if you call `printf`, it may change `errno`, and doing so is a common bug)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you fscanf into `q[i].addr`, there has not yet any memory been allocated to `q[i].addr`. Now anything can happen because the string is placed in memory that is not yours.

You should also check the return value of fscanf to be suer the data was properly read.

Comment: and how much should I allocate for that?